# Using V$SQL_PLAN Views for query plans

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to check the plan generated by query in oracle and instead of using explain plan I am trying to use V$SQL_PLAN views. Every query that is ran will have its plan stored in this view.(Please correct me if I am wrong).

Do we have to set autotrace on for this to work?

How to effectively use V$SQL_PLAN, V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS and V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL to display the plan in the same format as it is displayed when we use explain plan and 
**dbms_xplan.display**.

Comment: SET AUTOTRACE ON is a client feature in SQL*Plus - you don't have to do anything to get your plans to be stored in V$SQL_PLAN. Queries can't run w/o plans, and the plans are stored in that view. It's not clear what your question is, you want to build your own DBMS_XPLAN via queries? If so, why, what's wrong with DBMS_XPLAN? SQL Developer does this for you by the way as well, you could see what queries we use if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks jeff for the quick reply. I am not sure how to fetch the plan in the format that is shown by dbms_xplan.display.

Comment: Just run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query` and then `SELECT * FROM Table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`

Comment: just run dbms_xplan.display, and then you have your plan in the format you want - why does this not work?

Comment: There can be difference between what explain plan will give and what V$SQL_PLAN displays.

Comment: I have parametrized queries in an application and want to see the plan used when running these queries. I fear, when I copy the statement into SQL Developer and replace the bind params the query will be executed differently than it was.